# Querying datatable with Linq not working properly

Tags: c#, linq

I have a CSV that is converted to a datatable using this code..

```
public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
        string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (string header in headers)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(header);
        }
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = rows[i];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

when I try to run this query

```
var query = from a in res.AsEnumerable()
                     where a.Field<string>("Last Name") == "Dickinson"
                     select a;

        foreach (var b in query)
            Console.WriteLine(b);
```

all that I am getting returned is

> System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Data.DataRow]
>   System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Data.DataRow]
>   System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Data.DataRow]

I have looked on SO and seen examples, but I am doing something wrong and not sure what.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(b);`?

Comment: Tried that and it comes back with System.Data.DataRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the values you should cycle each column or use [.ItemArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach (var b in query)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",b.ItemArray));
```

Basically a row contains the value of each column like a dictionary

```
Header: [colName1][colName2][colName3]
Row1:   val1      val2      val3
Row2:   val1      valX      val3
Row3:   val1      val2      val3
```

for example

```
Console.WriteLine(row2["colName2"]);
```

will return valX

Comment: That worked, and i'll accept as the answer when allowed. Can you explain why it needed to be done this way? So I can understand why

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the link to it.

Comment: @Chris Ok, anyway i added a general explaination of DataRow logic

Comment: Kinda like using a dataset